What are the conclusions in Kant or Hegel that we can take to the bank?
What are the conclusions in Kant's or Hegel's philosophy which "we can take to the bank" according to current scholarship?
Thank you for any scholarly reference.

i have no idea what you mean by "take to the bank" and according to what current scholarship, what does that scholarship say about the bank and Hegel?

Did you cash out and take Descartes to your bank for a deposit? Though it seems you always carry his avatar with you as some currency here perhaps similar to your possibly always carried discretionary cash...

From Kant: that the existence of an objective thing is the observer's synthesis of idea and perception, and no more. E.g. from Heidegger's Basic Problems of Phenomenology, page 40:

In the proposition "A exists," "A is extant," an absolute positing is
involved. Being qua existence must not be confused with being in the
sense of "mere position" (being something). Whereas in the
Beweisgrund (p. 77) Kant characterizes existence as absolute position, he says in the Critique: "It is merely the position of a
thing, or of certain determinations in themselves. In logical use it
is merely the copula of a judgment."19 [as the observer joining concept to sense data: (the copula) - my comment.] Existence is not "mere
position." When Kant says that it is merely position, this
limitation holds with regard to the fact that it is not a real
predicate. In this context "merely" means "not relatively." Being is
not a real predicate either in the sense of "mere position" or in that
of "absolute position." In the passages cited, Kant defines the
meaning of being as position only with regard to being qua existence.
He is elucidating the concept of absolute position relevantly to the
connection of the problem with the proof of God's existence.
The preliminary interpretation of being as "mere position" and of
existence as "absolute position" should be kept in mind. In the
citation from Baumgarten the expression ponitur, position, also
appeared. For the real, too, the mere what of a thing, is posited in
the pure representing of the thing as in a certain way in itself. But
this positing is merely the positing of the possible, "mere position."
In one place Kant says that "as possibility was . . . merely a
position of the thing in relation to the understanding, so actuality
[existence] is at the same time a combining of it [the idea] with
perception [sensing]."20 Actuality, existence, is absolute position;
possibility, in contrast, is mere position. "The proposition 'God is
omnipotent' contains two concepts, each of which has its object: God
and omnipotence; the little word 'is' is not, in addition, a predicate
but only posits the predicate relatively to the
subject."21 In this positing of "is," of mere position,
nothing is asserted about existence. Kant says: "Hence also this being
[of the copula] is used quite correctly even in the case of the
relations which impossible things have to each other, "22
as when, for example, I say "The circle is square."


Critique of Pure Reason, B626.
Ibid., B287 n.; see also Beweisgrund, p. 79.
Critique of Pure Reason, B626-627.
Beweisgrund, p. 78.


While I very much appreciate a sourced, annotated answer on this site, how is Heidegger a good source for anything but Heidegger, again? Let alone current scholarship

@ChrisDegnen "the existence of an objective thing is the observer's synthesis of idea and perception" How is that a conclusion? This also seems fallacious to me. I certainly accept the rather obvious that the assertion that a thing exists follows from perception and possibly reasoning from perception, but this is assertion of existence, not existence itself. And this is certainly not what we mean by "existence".  Can you explain?

what is this fat random quote from heidegger supposed to clarify or answer?

That perception makes actuality. I.e. "if [a thing] is merely connected in the understanding with the formal conditions of experience, its object is called possible; if it is in connection with perception (sensation, as the matter of the senses), and through this determined by means of the understanding, then the object is actual; ..." B286

@PhilipKlöcking I think Heidegger's explanation of Kant's position is quite informative and represents it fairly. Kant's position has been superseded by postmodernism, but it is still a useful stepping-stone.

@ChrisDegnen "then the object is actual" Again, how is that a conclusion? Where are the premises, where is the reasoning?

The conclusion and revelation is that the truth of the thing-in-itself is not a part of the actuality of the thing, and that the thing's objective existence is far more tenuous than one might have preferred as a realist wanting to know the thing-in-itself.

Heidegger proceeds to add nuance to Kant's conclusion: "Can existence be equated with the per­ceived existent? In this case it would itself be a being, something real. But the uncontested negative import of the Kantian thesis says that existence is not such a being. ... Let us take another step in meeting Kant halfway and interpreting him favorably. Let us say: Existence cannot be equated with the perceived existent, but it can quite well, perhaps, be equated with the being-perceived of the perceived, its perceivedness." (Basic Problems, p. 48.)
